# Longest Snake Sequence in an Array

Tags: python, arrays, sequence

**Question :** A set of numbers separated by space is passed as input. The program must print the largest snake sequence present in the numbers. A snake sequence is made up of adjacent numbers such that for each number, the number on the right or left is +1 or -1 of it's value. If multiple snake sequences of maximum length is possible print the snake sequence appearing in the natural input order.

**Example Input/Output 1:**

Input:

```
9 8 7 5 3 0 1 -2 -3 1 2
```

Output:

```
3 2 1 0 1
```

**Example Input/Output 2:**

Input:

```
-5 -4 -3 -1 0 1 4 6 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0 2 -3 9
```

Output:

```
6 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0 -1 0 1 2
```

**Example Input/Output 3:**

Input:

```
5 6 7 9 8 8
```

Output:

```
5 6 7 8 9 8
```

I have searched online & have only found references to find a snake sequence when a grid of numbers is given & not an array.

**My Solution so far :**
Create a 2D Array containing all the numbers from input as 1 value and the 2nd value being the max length sequence that can be generated starting from that number. But this doesn't always generate the max length sequence and doesn't work at all when there are 2 snakes of max length.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: My idea is this : Create a 2D array containing all the numbers present in the input as the index & the 2nd value being the max length sequence that can be generated going from that number.

Comment: @PaulRooney But this doesn't always give the largest sequence & also it fails test cases where there are two snakes of max length.

Comment: Don't just describe your solution, post your code. Does it work?

Comment: @LutzHorn As I have said in the solution it does not always generate the max length sequence & doesn't work when there are 2 max length snakes so I am searching for an alternate solution which solves both the problems

Comment: This seems to be an instance of the [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which is NP-complete. Basically, you could create a graph from your set of numbers, connecting each pair of numbers with difference of 1 by an edge. The longest snake sequence is then the longest simple path in that graph.

Comment: @tobias_k Could u explain this to me in a detailed way since I have not studied the implementation of Longest Path Problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the order in the original set of numbers does not matter, as seems to be the case in your question, this seems to be an instance of the [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which is NP-hard.

Think of it that way: You can create a graph from your numbers, with edges between all pairs of nodes that have a difference of one. Now, the longest simple (acyclic) path in this graph is your solution. Your first example would correspond to this graph and path. (Note that there are two *1* nodes for the two ones in the input set.)

[image]

While this in itself does not solve your problem, it should help you getting started finding an algorithm to solve (or approximate) it, now that you know a better/more common name for the problem.

---

One algorithm works like this: Starting from each of the numbers, determine the "adjacent" numbers and do sort of a depth-first search through the graph to determine the longest path. Remember to temporarily remove the visited nodes from the graph. This has a worstcase complexity of *O(2<sup>n</sup>)* <sup>1)</sup>, but apparently it's sufficient for your examples.

```
def longest_snake(numbers, counts, path):
    best = path
    for n in sorted(counts, key=numbers.index):
        if counts[n] > 0 and (path == [] or abs(path[-1] - n) == 1):
            counts[n] -= 1
            res = longest_snake(numbers, counts, path + [n])
            if len(res) > len(best):
                best = res
            counts[n] += 1
    return best
```

Example:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> numbers = list(map(int, "9 8 7 5 3 0 1 -2 -3 1 2".split()))
>>> longest_snake(numbers, Counter(numbers), [])
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1]
```

Note that this algorithm will reliably find a maximum "snake" sequence, using no number more often than allowed. However, it may not find the *specific* sequence that's expected as the output, i.e. "the snake sequence appearing in the natural input order", whatever that's supposed to mean.
To get closer to the "natural order", you might try the numbers in the same order as they appear in the input (as I did with `sorted`), but that does not work perfectly, either. Anyway, I'm sure you can figure out the rest by yourself.

---

<sup>1)</sup> In this special case, the graph has a branching factor of 2, thus O(2<sup>n</sup>); in the more general case, the complexity would be closer to O(n!).

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k. This will help me solve the first problem i.e Finding the Longest Snake. But what do i do when there are two paths of longest length & I have to take the one which is naturally occurring in the input ?

Comment: Check the last line of the question & the 3rd Sample Input/Output. How do u check if a path occurs naturally in the input ?

Comment: @DarthShadow I am still not sure what this is supposed to mean. Anyway, I think this part should be left as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Comment: This method is not giving the correct answer for any example other than the mentioned one.

Comment: I don't mean the correct answer to be the one that is appearing in natural input order. The method specified does not even print the longest path for the 2nd & 3rd case & instead repeats nodes which occur only once multiple times. Check it out here : [ideOne](https://ideone.com/SwlZOH)

Comment: BTW "natural input order" means if the one of the maximum length paths is a subset of the input or the input itself then that should be preferred over the other possibilities.

Comment: @DarthShadow Can not reproduce. For me, all the snakes are maximal and no nodes are repeated more often than they occurr in the input. Please check again. About "natural order": This seems not to be the case for any of the examples, either.

Comment: It doesn't print the maximum snake for Example 2. About "natural order". It comes into play only for the 3rd example as it has 2 possible maximum length snakes : "5 6 7 8 9 8"  and "8 9 8 7 6 5". But as "5 6 7 8 9 8" occurs in the natural order (same as the input sequence) it is printed as the output.

Comment: @DarthShadow This is getting kind of lengthy, but anyway: What _are_ you getting for input2? As I said, it works for me. The "snake" has length 13, which is the same as yours. And for input 3: It is _not_ the same as the input. That whole "natural order" constraint is entirely unclear to me. If _you_ know what it means, how about you try to figure that part out yourself? Given that this is probably a homework problem I think that I've helped enough already.

Comment: [0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4] is the answer I am getting for 2nd one. U can forget the natural order part. I will do that myself.