# Longest Snake Sequence in a list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, sequence

**Question :** A set of numbers separated by space is passed as input. The program must print the largest snake sequence present in the numbers. A snake sequence is made up of adjacent numbers such that for each number, the number on the right or left is +1 or -1 of it's value. If multiple snake sequences of maximum length is possible print the snake sequence appearing in the natural input order.

**Example Input/Output 1:**

Input:

```
9 8 7 5 3 0 1 -2 -3 1 2
```

Output:

```
3 2 1 0 1
```

**Example Input/Output 2:**

Input:

```
-5 -4 -3 -1 0 1 4 6 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0 2 -3 9
```

Output:

```
6 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0 -1 0 1 2
```

**Example Input/Output 3:**

Input:

```
5 6 7 9 8 8
```

Output:

```
5 6 7 8 9 8
```

I found a program in Python from this link:
["Longest Snake in an array"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706114/longest-snake-sequence-in-an-array)
as below but it fails to fulfill the following test case. As mentioned in the question in case of two or more sequence of maximum length the program has to print the snake sequence appearing in the Natural input order. I suspect that this the parameter that is creating the problem.

The output should be what this program is showing since the point of difference is 8 and 10.(If I am not wrong about what natural order means) 8 appearing before 10 in the input list should be taken into the sequence for correct output instead of 10 but that is not the expected output.

```
"""
Test case Input:
4 3 1 6 7 8 8 21 7 8 9 13 -1 2 14 9 10 11 10 9

Expected Output:
6 7 8 7 8 9 10 11 10 9 8 9

Your Program Output:
6 7 8 7 8 9 8 9 10 9 10 11
"""

from collections import Counter
def longest_snake(numbers,counts,path):
        best = path
        for n in sorted(counts, key = numbers.index, reverse=True):
                if counts[n] > 0 and (path == [] or abs(path[-1] - n) == 1):
                        counts[n] -= 1
                        res = longest_snake(numbers,counts,path + [n])
                        if (len(res) > len(best)):
                                best = res
                        counts[n] += 1
        return best
if __name__ == '__main__':
        numbers = list(map(int, raw_input().split()))
        output = longest_snake(numbers,Counter(numbers),[])[::-1]
        print(' '.join(map(str,output)))
```

Comment: How can `3 2 1 0 1` be the output in example 1? 3 does not appear next to 2 anywhere in the input. Could you clarify how it should work?

Comment: As I already discussed with that other guy: You'll have to clarify _exactly_ what "in natural order" is supposed to mean. If you don't know, ask your teacher for clarification. How is `6 7 8 7 8 9 10 11 10 9 8 9` more "in natural order" than `6 7 8 7 8 9 8 9 10 9 10 11`?

Comment: I think I see it. The output sequence is not a subsequence of the input, but you can use the input values to create a snake sequence in any order? Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: The numbers don't have to be adjacent in the input order. The next number can be picked up anywhere from the input list.

Comment: @camz Yes, as I understood it, you can use any order, but in case there is more than one solution, order seems to matter somehow. Maybe it's about having as many "chunks" that are in the same order as in the original list...

Comment: BTW, why the double-reverse with `sorted(..., reverse=True)` and then `[::-1]` on the output? Did that make a difference for some test cases?

Comment: Each of your three examples of input and output seems to be modifying the input data sequence in some way, or abusing the rules (notably the key word 'adjacent' in _a snake sequence is made up of adjacent numbers such that for each number, the number on the right or left is +1 or -1 of its value_).  Either you've been sloppy in transcribing your examples, or you've not described the algorithm correctly.  It is nigh on impossible to help you until it is clear what you really need.

Comment: I m sorry for being so but the question has been pasted exactly as it was.
I may have figure it out why 10 was used in place of 8. The reason may be the index of 10 is greater than the previous number 9. While 8 appears before 9. Therefore 10 is in a natural order more than the number 8. The search for the next number should go only forward and go back only when the end of the list has been reached. You're correct about your algorithm @tobias_k Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tobias_k Yes the double-reverse was to get through some of the test cases.

Comment: @Shashank I m sorry if I am mistaken but the last two numbers of the input are already used in my output as you can see there are already three 9s and two 10s in my output. So how can I have a longer snake sequence? Please explain.

Comment: @arnavprospeed Sorry I was wrong in my comment regarding your output. But I don't understand their expected output still. How do they manage to end their expected output with "8 9"?

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight variation of my algorithm. It still does not satisfy all the test cases, but it's much closer to what I understand to be the "natural input order".

```
def longest_snake(numbers, counts, path, pos=0):
    visited = set()                                # keep track of visited nodes
    best, total = path, pos                        # best path and best pos
    for i in range(len(numbers)):                  # for one more round...
        n = numbers[(pos + i) % len(numbers)]      # wrap around edges, get n
        if n not in visited and counts[n] > 0 and (path == [] or abs(path[-1] - n) == 1):
            visited.add(n)
            counts[n] -= 1
            res, t = longest_snake(numbers, counts, path + [n], pos + i)
            if len(res) > len(best) or (len(res) == len(best) and t < total):
                best, total = res, t               # longer path or fewer steps
            counts[n] += 1
    return best, total                             # return both path and total steps
```

Here's how it works now:

- it keeps track of the current position in the input list (`pos`)
- when recursing, it continues at that position, passing `pos + i` to the recursive call, thus trying "chunks" of numbers first
- if `pos + i` is greater than the length of the input, it wraps around to the beginning
- if two snake paths have the same length, it takes the path that has a lower total position, i.e. for which less advancement in the input and less "wrapping around" to the beginning was necessary

As I said, it's much closer to the "natural input order", but still not perfect. Here's an example:

```
6 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0 -1 0 1 2  # expected output
4 5 4 3 4 3 2 1 0 -1 0 1 2  # my output
```

---

In the end, it all boils down to how "natural input order" is defined. Take the first test case, i.e. `9 8 7 5 3 0 1 -2 -3 1 2`: This version of the code yields `1 0 1 2 3`, but expected is `3 2 1 0 1`. But why? My result has one pair of numbers that were next to each other in the input (`1 2`), while the expected output has none, and mine also has fewer "steps" (two times around and then up to `3`, while the expected has two times around and up to one of the `1`s).

Or to put it differently: You can take my algorithm and change the condition to this:

```
if len(res) > len(best) or (len(res) == len(best) and isMoreOrdered(numbers, res, best)):`
```

If you can define the function `isMoreOrdered(numbers, new_path, old_path)`, then you are done. But from the few examples and the wording of the question, I certainly can not tell.

Anyway, maybe this gave you some ideas and you can figure out the rest on your own.