# Longest Snake Sequence

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, sequence, permutation

**Question** : A set of numbers separated by space is passed as input. The program must print the largest snake sequence present in the numbers. A snake sequence is made up of adjacent numbers such that for each number, the number on the right or left is +1 or -1 of it's value. If multiple snake sequences of maximum length is possible print the snake sequence appearing in the natural input order.

**Example Input/Output 1:**

**Input**:

5 6 7 9 8 8

**Output**:

5 6 7 8 9 8

8 9 8 7 6 5

**Example Input/Output 2:**

**Input**:

9 8 7 5 3 0 1 -2 -3 1 2

**Output**:

3 2 1 0 1

```
void doPermute(int[] in, StringBuffer out, boolean[] used, int length, int level, StringBuffer max) {
    if (level == length) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < out.length(); i++) {
            if (Math.abs(Character.getNumericValue(out.charAt(i)) - Character.getNumericValue(out.charAt(i - 1))) != 1) {
                //System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(i) - Character.getNumericValue(i - 1) + "  " + i + "   yes");
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            max.append(out + " ");

        }

        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (used[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        out.append(in[i]);
        used[i] = true;
        doPermute(in, out, used, length, level + 1, max);
        used[i] = false;
        out.setLength(out.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

**As i am using StringBuffer my code passed the test cases that contains positive value (first test case) but failed in test cases containing negative values(second test case).**

**Update**:-
I replaced `stringbuffer` with `Integer[]`  and made few changes.it works fine for smaller inputs of length 8 or 9. How to make it fast for larger inputs of length 13 to 15?

Comment: How did it fail? What output did you get instead? What is your question? Have you made any effort to debug the program and narrow down where the problem might be?

Comment: using String buffer it take -2 as - and 2

Comment: Can you be more detailed please? What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: @tnw in test case 1, all are positive value, so it permute as 567889,then 567898 and so on while in case of negative value say 5 6 7 8 8 -9, it permute as 5 6 7 8 8 - 9. So it consider '-' sign as a character instead of '-9'.

Comment: Well, your for-loop in `doPermute` is getting one character at a time from the `StringBuffer` and working on them.  What makes you think it *should* treat `-` and `9` as `-9`?  If you want to parse the contents as numbers, you need to do that.

Comment: @azurefrog I actually made it for positive no. For negative, I tried with **Integer** array by replacing String Buffer but the permutation is not accurate..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706114/longest-snake-sequence-in-an-array

This is the exact same question being asked !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing the process using an array of integers?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine(); //The numbers entered in string format separated by spaces
String ss = s.split(" "); //Numbers separated by space will be put as individual numbers in a String array but each number is still in string format
int l = ss.length, i = 0;
int[] n = new int[l]; //The integer array which will store the values
for(i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    n[i] = Integer.parseInt(ss[i]);  //Has integers now instead of string numbers
}
```

There might be creation of a few extra arrays but then calling the `Character.getNumericValue()` function repeatedly can also reduce efficiency. Also might solve your StringBuffer problem.

But SkillRack is very annoying anyway.

Comment: I tried but it takes a lot of time for larger values. anything to make it fast?

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison isn't finding adjacent numbers for negative values.
For example: `Abs(-2) - (-3) = 5`  but `-2` and `-3` should be adjacent.
Ok. I see you're parsing - and digit separately.
Given the requirement of what a snake sequence is, the longest snake sequence for "5 6 7 9 8 8" is "5 6 7". The output listed above does not correspond to the definition: " adjacent numbers such that for each number, the number on the right or left is +1 or -1 of it's value". How does "5 6 7 8 9 8" meet the definition of snake sequence for "5 6 7 9 8 8"? Sorry I couldn't help. 
You might want to parse the code into Integers, store the longest sequences in a map).

```
@Test
public void testSnake(){
    String t2 = "9 8 7 5 3 0 1 -2 -3 1 2";
    List<String> numsStr = Arrays.asList(t2.split(" "));
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<Integer,List<Integer> > numMap = new HashMap();

    numsStr.forEach((s) -> {
        Integer val = Integer.decode(s);
        nums.add(val);
    });

    nums.forEach((num) -> {
        System.out.println("num: " + num);
        // track longest sequence, store in numMap
    });
    // Print numMap
}
```

Comment: problem is with string buffer method as while executing it takes negative value as a separate character.ex (-2 as - & 2).

Comment: "567898" for "567988" is right as their is +1 or -1 difference between the digits.

Comment: I thought the requirement for adjacent numbers meant they had to be adjacent in the input stream. In their natural order.

Comment: i made few changes and it worked fine but for larger value it took a lot of time. Any idea to make it faster?

Comment: Get rid of the recursion. You have an O(n^2) recursive algorithm. You can do the solution with O(n) performance without recursion. I'm on travel and don't have my computer at the moment so can't post code. You can iterate over the input, put each item in a TreeMap<item value, num items>, track if you've used an item in a chain with numItems value, for each item, look in map and see if there are values to left and right, store longest chain in List<List<Integer>, print list of lists at the end. That's what I'd do in a nutshell.

Comment: will that print all combination? I'll try and if possible please post the code.